# check for python with ansible

Tags: python, ansible, devops

I have template that check if the python is installed by ansible
I do not know how it works
can someone explain it more?

```
- name: check for python
  stat:
    path: "{{ item }}"
  changed_when: false
  failed_when: false
  register: systempython
  with_items:
    - /usr/bin/python
    - /usr/bin/python3
    - /usr/libexec/platform-python
```

Answer (score 1):

It iterates over items mentioned in `with_items` and uses [stats](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html) ansible module to get the file properties. Properties would be returned if file exists. If that happens, then `register` will inform ansible to store the return value of `stats` to `systempython` var